# Restarting app after displaying data values and graph

Tags: java, android, sensors

I've an android app which  is getting external sensor values and showing as a data view  and graph view in android as well showing data view in webservice. Once i was able to getting and showing values but after getting few data its going to previous activity. Can somebody help me to find errors. Logcat is attached with this

```
06-16 08:45:21.992: D/dalvikvm(9925): GC_CONCURRENT freed 300K, 8% free 9493K/10311K, paused 27ms+4ms, total 74ms
06-16 08:45:21.992: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 39ms
06-16 08:45:21.992: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 40ms
06-16 08:45:21.992: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 39ms
06-16 08:45:21.992: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 36ms
06-16 08:45:21.992: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 35ms
06-16 08:45:21.992: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
06-16 08:45:21.992: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
06-16 08:45:21.992: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
06-16 08:45:21.992: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
06-16 08:45:21.992: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
06-16 08:45:22.000: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
06-16 08:45:22.000: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
06-16 08:45:22.000: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
06-16 08:45:22.000: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 39ms
06-16 08:45:22.000: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
06-16 08:45:22.000: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 39ms
06-16 08:45:22.000: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 39ms
06-16 08:45:22.000: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
06-16 08:45:22.000: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 40ms
06-16 08:45:22.007: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 45ms
06-16 08:45:22.070: D/dalvikvm(9925): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 12K, 8% free 9950K/10759K, paused 63ms, total 63ms
06-16 08:45:22.070: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 87ms
06-16 08:45:22.070: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 106ms
06-16 08:45:22.070: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 107ms
06-16 08:45:22.078: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 90ms
06-16 08:45:22.078: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 113ms
06-16 08:45:22.078: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 114ms
06-16 08:45:22.078: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 125ms
06-16 08:45:22.078: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 125ms
06-16 08:45:22.093: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 125ms
06-16 08:45:22.093: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 125ms
06-16 08:45:22.093: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 127ms
06-16 08:45:22.093: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 111ms
06-16 08:45:22.093: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 111ms
06-16 08:45:22.093: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 113ms
06-16 08:45:22.101: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 113ms
06-16 08:45:22.101: D/dalvikvm(9925): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 116ms
06-16 08:45:22.109: I/System.out(9925): Response Code : 406
06-16 08:45:22.164: D/dalvikvm(9925): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 66K, 7% free 10616K/11399K, paused 52ms, total 53ms
06-16 08:45:22.171: W/dalvikvm(9925): threadid=19: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410ff2a0)
06-16 08:45:22.179: I/System.out(9925): Response Code : 406
06-16 08:45:22.179: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(9925): readNative
06-16 08:45:22.179: D/Shimmer(9925): MSGREAD
06-16 08:45:22.179: I/System.out(9925): Response Code : 406
06-16 08:45:22.187: E/Log E(9925):  >>>>> Array INO: 0.38613861386138615 0.7524752475247525 6.445544554455446
06-16 08:45:22.187: I/System.out(9925): Response Code : 406
06-16 08:45:22.187: W/dalvikvm(9925): threadid=43: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410ff2a0)
06-16 08:45:29.054: W/Bundle(10074): Key patientid expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1061)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraph.PatientActivity.onCreate(PatientActivity.java:29)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
06-16 08:45:29.062: W/Bundle(10074):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 08:45:29.250: I/System.out(10074): Response Code : 200
06-16 08:45:29.281: D/dalvikvm(10074): GC_CONCURRENT freed 247K, 10% free 7525K/8327K, paused 5ms+3ms, total 31ms
06-16 08:45:33.453: E/SensorManager(10074): thread start
06-16 08:45:33.453: D/SensorManager(10074): registerListener :: handle = 1  name= BMA254 Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@418b5340
06-16 08:45:33.476: D/SensorManager(10074): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@418b5340
06-16 08:45:33.476: D/Sensors(10074): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
06-16 08:45:33.476: I/Sensors(10074): sendDelay --- 200000000
06-16 08:45:33.476: D/SensorManager(10074): JNI - sendDelay
06-16 08:45:33.476: I/SensorManager(10074): Set normal delay = true
06-16 08:45:33.476: D/SensorManager(10074): registerListener :: handle = 1  name= BMA254 Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@418dccd0
06-16 08:45:33.484: D/SensorManager(10074): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@418dccd0
06-16 08:45:33.484: D/Sensors(10074): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
06-16 08:45:33.484: I/Sensors(10074): sendDelay --- 200000000
06-16 08:45:33.484: D/SensorManager(10074): JNI - sendDelay
06-16 08:45:33.484: I/SensorManager(10074): Set normal delay = true
06-16 08:45:33.492: D/SensorManager(10074): registerListener :: handle = 1  name= BMA254 Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@418dccd0
06-16 08:45:33.687: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10074): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-16 08:45:33.687: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10074): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-16 08:45:33.710: D/SensorManager(10074): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@418dccd0
06-16 08:45:33.710: D/Sensors(10074): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
06-16 08:45:33.710: I/Sensors(10074): sendDelay --- 200000000
06-16 08:45:33.710: D/SensorManager(10074): JNI - sendDelay
06-16 08:45:33.710: I/SensorManager(10074): Set normal delay = true
06-16 08:45:33.968: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10074): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: `Key patientid expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.` is the key.  You need to find out why that message is being returned at `com.shimmerresearch.shimmergraph.PatientActivity.onCreate(PatientActivity.java:29)` An int is coming back, so a null is returned since it wasn't a string.

Comment: Oh, and that's probably killing the activity which is what you are interpreting as going back to the previous.

Comment: Can you show us this line : PatientActivity.java:29

Comment: Jeremy Miller : yes i tried to find out but nothing got

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_patient);
  
  details  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PatientDetailsTxt);
  
  patientid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("patientid");
  email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
   
  String[] args = {email};

Comment: Actually I created Login Screen, Patientdetail screen, Shimmer Graph which is showing 4 options 1. i need to connect a shimmer 2. Select Sensor type 3. Start streaming First 2 options work but when i click on "Start Streaming" it returns of patient activity screen.....

Comment: Please edit the question to add code / logcat output. It's difficult to read without the formatting. also, which one exactly is the line 29 ?

Comment: patientid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("patientid");